# Credentials Manager Activity Analysis

Tags: sql

The result should have the following columns: mac/type/started_at/ended_at/activities
mac-account MAC address
type-sequence activity type
started_at-date and time the sequence started
ended_at-date and time sequence ended
activities-number of activities in a sequence

QUESTIONS
The result should be sorted in ascending order by mac then in ascending order by started_at

Only sequences of 3 or more consecutive error-type actions should be included in the result. The table below is already the data from the original.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS activities;

-- create accounts table
CREATE TABLE accounts (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  mac INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- create activities table
CREATE TABLE activities (
  account_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  dt INTEGER NOT NULL,
  type INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
);
-- insert some accounts values
INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (1, 'C4-85-20-F3-E9-CD');
INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (2, 'CB-5D-05-EE-05-97');
INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (3, '5C-40-A9-D4-25-77');

-- insert some activities values
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 10, 'SUCCESS');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 11, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 12, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 13, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 14, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 15, 'SUCCESS');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 16, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 17, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 18, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (1, 19, 'SUCCESS');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (2, 10, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (2, 11, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (2, 12, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (2, 13, 'SUCCESS');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (2, 14, 'SUCCESS');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (2, 15, 'SUCCESS');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (3, 11, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (3, 12, 'ERROR');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (3, 13, 'SUCCESS');
INSERT INTO activities VALUES (3, 14, 'SUCCESS');


SELECT "account_id", COUNT(*), min("dt"), max("dt") FROM activities WHERE type = 'ERROR' 
GROUP BY "account_id"
```

EXPECTED outcome:

```
MAC                 | TYPE | started_at |  ended_at |   total_activities 
C4-85-20-F3-E9-CD | ERROR | 11         | 14        | 4
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: also that is not valid mysql code are you sure you tagged the right database system

Comment: @nbk can you help me?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically it is gap and island probkem

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT 
   account_id
  ,dt
,type
  , IF(type <> LAG(type) OVER(ORDER BY account_id,dt) OR LAG(type) OVER(ORDER BY account_id, dt) IS NULL,1,0) sm
FROM activities)
,CTE2 as (
  SELECT 
   account_id
  ,dt
,type
,SUM(sm) OVER(ORDER BY account_id,dt)  grp
  FROM cte)
SELECT
mac,
  
  MIN(dt) as min_dt, MAX(dt) as MAX , count(*) cnt
FROM CTE2 c JOIN accounts a ON c.account_id = a.id
WHERE type = 'ERROR'
GROUP BY grp, mac
HAVING cnt > 3
```

| mac | min_dt | MAX | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C4-85-20-F3-E9-CD | 11 | 14 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xIO0OxU9)

or with `CASE WHEN` which can be used by other Databases not as the sample before that would only work with MySQL 8.x

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT 
   account_id
  ,dt
,type
  , CASE WHEN type <> LAG(type) OVER(ORDER BY account_id,dt) OR LAG(type) OVER(ORDER BY account_id, dt) IS NULL
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END sm
FROM activities)
,CTE2 as (
  SELECT 
   account_id
  ,dt
,type
,SUM(sm) OVER(ORDER BY account_id,dt)  grp
  FROM cte)
SELECT
mac,
  
  MIN(dt) as min_dt, MAX(dt) as MAX , count(*) cnt
FROM CTE2 c JOIN accounts a ON c.account_id = a.id
WHERE type = 'ERROR'
GROUP BY grp, mac
HAVING cnt > 3
```

| mac | min_dt | MAX | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C4-85-20-F3-E9-CD | 11 | 14 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c36Eck8T)

Comment: A `case` instead of `if` would make it more portable, and almost ANSI SQL compliant. (No dbms tagged.)